# noobie web-builder, about building html gallery

Tags: css, web, gallery, helper, catalog

i asked couple days ago and i realised my question wasnt clear enough. 
so ill ask it again more clearly.
i'm about to finish a website for local business,my website is based on bootstrap 3,and a little bit of jquery.im now working on the web catalog.Im searching for dynamic way to show 20 products each time,,without making new html page for each 20 product.im not looking for the code for it,
im just looking for a direction from you guys, cuz it seems that i cant find any good idea,
and i have to finish it until thursday. thank you guys. ! (:

Comment: From one noob to another - I'm very sympathetic. Your ISP probably can give you access to a MySQL database, so you'll need to learn about Ajax and the PHP to send info back. Here are a couple of pages that I have used that might give you a little help to get you started. - https://www.sites.google.com/site/timspqr/home/programs/javascript-code/ajax-callbacks ///// PHP on HTML page https://www.sites.google.com/site/timspqr/home/programs/php/php-code-on-html-page /// Server side code for making a json array https://www.sites.google.com/site/timspqr/home/programs/php/make-json-array

Comment: can i make static database of objects, and display then using php and/or ajax? :D

Comment: Yes, you could create a file on the server and read that file with ajax.

Comment: php file? or something else?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - xml, html, script, json, jsonp, text.

Comment: well i searched for the internet for a while and im pretty confused.

Comment: I'm working on an html/javascript example with a server .txt file. Give me a few hours to spiff it up.

Comment: i taught i can just create object, that contains 3 properties:1)string-for price 2)string-for description 3)string- url for img.. make a large file of all the elements,and in ajax or what ever make a functin that load 20 objects each time and place them correctly in a div.. but i just cant understand how even to make the file.. how do i make a file of objects?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there are two files that you need to move to your server.

The first is the .html file that does the "work" - it is below. The salient points are:

1. Standard HTML file with the typical header containing the usual styling, title, and links to the Google CDN library.
2. Button inside a div - the div allows the button to be moved around.
3. A div to contain the data (.putmehere).
4. The javascript at the bottom - "ready function" that all pages should have, ".on('click' " to start the ajax call, and the ajax call.

The presidents.txt file is just a list of all the presidents I found on the internet. You'll have to make something more organized and you'll have to figure out a way of parsing it.

Both of the files should be moved to your server in the same subdirectory. Then from your browser, just put in the name of the html file, hit enter and you're ready to go!

JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>text file read</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style>

.buttonholder {
          width: 150px;
          height: 40px;
          margin: 10px auto;
}
.putmehere {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class='buttonholder'>
  <button id='clickme'>CLICK ME</button>
</div>

<div class='putmehere'></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#clickme').on('click', function(){
                                           $.ajax({
                                                   url: "presidents.txt",
                                              dataType: "text"
                                                   })
                                                     .done(function(data){
                                                                          console.log( data );
                                                                          $('.putmehere').html( data );
                                                                          });
                                                    });//end ajax
                             });//end ready function

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow thank you ! i still having a little bit of hard time understanding the code lol.. but i hope ill figure it out,do you have skype? i just want to understand better your work :D thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

depending on your code behind I would suggest to build a class for your product pages (maybe a simple PHP file also would work in your case. without deeper knowledge about your project I can only guess...)

I hope it helps.

EDIT: if you use jquery, it would be easy to implement AJAX to dynamically reload content for your page.

Comment: whats AJAX excatly? and here it it : www acol co il

Comment: AJAX stands for Asynchronus Javascript And XML and is used to load data (as the name says) asynchronuosly. This means you don't have to reload a full page or site to change it's content. Instead you can use AJAX requests.
If you have never worked with it before it might be easier if you look it up with a search engine of your choice and read relevant articles... you might get information easier on that way since you know what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: it's loading the contect from certain database? AJAX is server or client side? thank you (: and how you think about your website? i know it's probably not in your original lang, but how is the design?

Comment: AJAX is Client sided, but you need server sided setup since you get responses from the server. If I could help you I would be glad if you upvote my answer ;). About your design: even if it's not a question to be posted on here... looks simple and well, even if I would make it different..

"simplicity is the ultimate form of sophistication" - leonardo da vinci

Comment: it tells me that i can upvote because my reputation lol, what can i do to increase it? i really want to voteup you.. thank you (: